# CSS global :nth-of-type selector (:nth-of-class)

Tags: css, css-selectors

What CSS selector can be used to select all odd elements inside a parent, but which are not necessarily siblings?

```
<div id="parent">
    <div>
        <div class="element">A</div>            
    </div>
    <div class="element">A</div>   
    <div class="element">A</div>         
    <div>
        <div class="element">A</div>            
    </div>
    <div class="element">A</div>            
<div>
```

What I want is to select every `element` in `parent` and apply a style only for odd-indexed ones in this list.

[Demo on jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/hP7vk/)

​

Comment: Not possible even in css3, you should consider doing this with JS

Comment: Well, I could add using javascript the class "odd" for every odd element inside the parent div, but I was hoping for a CSS-only soution :D

Comment: So, currently solved the problem using: $('#parent .element:odd').each(function () {$(this).addClass('odd');});

Comment: ...and you beat me to it ;-)

Comment: There is no such CSS selector; all `:nth-*` pseudo-classes currently match by sibling only.

Answer (score 1):

While it uses JavaScript, you could style the odd element without altering your markup:

```
$('.parent .element:odd').css('font-weight', 'bold');
```

​
http://jsfiddle.net/ansonhoyt/MfxYF/

Comment: This is how I currently "solved" this problem, see the comment above.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get it down to single selector, but with two...

```
.parent > .element:nth-of-type(2n){
  background:#afa !important;
}
.parent > div:nth-of-type(2n) > .element {
  background:#afa !important;
}
```

[View it on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/skNfL/)

Comment: Hmm... This must also work when there are multiple elements inside the div: http://jsfiddle.net/skNfL/1/

Answer (score 1):

It took a long time, but as of Aug '22 this is now possible in Chrome and Safari (Firefox is still working on it):

```css
.parent .element{
    width:250px;
    background:#faa;
    text-align:center;
}

.parent .element:nth-of-type(2n),
.parent :has(.element):nth-of-type(2n) .element {
    background:#afa !important;
}
```

```html
This:
<div class="parent">
<div>
    <div class="element">1</div>      
    <div class="element">2</div>   
    <div class="element">3</div>        
</div>
<div class="element">4</div>   
<div class="element">5</div>         
<div>
    <div class="element">6</div>            
</div>
<div class="element">7</div>            
</div>
<br>
Should look like this:
<div class="parent">
<div class="element">1</div>            
<div class="element">2</div>   
<div class="element">3</div>         
<div class="element">4</div>            
<div class="element">5</div>
<div class="element">6</div>            
<div class="element">7</div>      
<div>
```