# Select even elements of a particular class in CSS

Tags: css

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
  <li class="a">Hi-1</li>
  <li class="b">Hi-2</li>
  <li class="b">Hi-3</li>
  <li class="a">Hi-4</li>
  <li class="b">Hi-5</li>
  <li class="b">Hi-6</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
 li{
   list-style:none;
 }
.a{
   color:blue;
 }
.b:nth-child(odd){
  color:red;
}
.b:nth-child(even){
  color:violet;
}
```

[click here](http://jsfiddle.net/Venugopal/g2qke/)

I want Hi-2, Hi-5 in red and Hi-3, Hi-6 in violet.

Comment: Possibly duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17458582/css-selectors-nth-childeven-odd-with-class/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10921809/css3-nth-of-type-restricted-to-class

Comment: I think you want an nth-of-class selector - but that doesn't exist.. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13975475/css-global-nth-of-type-selector-nth-of-class (possible duplicate)

Answer (score 0):

How specified in other question in the comments, you can't restrict the usage of those pseudoclasses: so without using `nth-*` pseudoclasses and without changing your markup you could give this style

```
ul li:first-child + .b, .a ~ .a + .b { color: red; }
.b + .b { color: violet; }
```

example [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ivujac/1/)

Answer (score 0):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sbsBB/)

```
li{
    list-style:none;
}
.a{
    color:blue;
}
.b:nth-child(2n),.b:nth-child(5n){
    color:red;
}
.b:nth-child(6n), .b:nth-child(3n){
    color:violet;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

with different and pratical codes (to me) :
HTML:

```
  <ul>
  <li class="c">Hi-1</li>
  <li class="b">Hi-2</li>
  <li class="a">Hi-3</li>
  <li class="c">Hi-4</li>
  <li class="b">Hi-5</li>
  <li class="a">Hi-6</li>
  </ul>
```

CSS:

```
li {
list-style : none;
}
.a {
color: violet;
}
.b {
color: red;
}
.c {
color : blue;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WESnh/

Answer (score 0):

Use this CSS:

```
.b:nth-of-type(3n-1){
  color:red;
}
.b:nth-of-type(3n-3){
  color:violet;
}
```

**[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/DBkWA/)**