# Css selectors help needed

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have this composition :

```
<div class="theclass1"> 
     <input type="checkbox" id ="1">
     <div>
        <div>
          <div>
          <label for="1">bla bla</label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <input type="checkbox" id ="yy">
        <label for ="yy">other</label>
     </div>

  <div class="theclass2">  
    <input type="checkbox" id ="2">
    <div>
      <div>
         <div> 
         <label for="2">bla bla</label>
        </div>
      </div>
        <input type="checkbox" id ="xx">
        <label for ="xx">other</label>
    </div>  
  </div>

</div>
```

I want (and I am super cofussed) to apply css styles to the label but only the first of 'theclass1'

I'm playing with first-of-type, first child,  +div  >div>div ,etc... without success.

Maybe somebody can explain me how to made this and if possible using some examples. I have a lot of troubles to understand the meaning of  space, + and  > selectors. Also... I think it can have more than one solution ?

I'd need code to style only the first label of theclass1, or the first inside >div>div>div but only this one. And something similar for theclass2. 
Now I have a polluted css and undesirable results.

(The div 'theclass2' is inside div theclass1.)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please give your question a proper title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem is not the CSS only, There are serious semantics errors in your HTML

- `id` attribute name must not start with numbers

taken from HTML4 document of w3c

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be
>   followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"),
>   underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

- so much nesting , why these extra parent div div and div?
- now first you fix the HTML nodes then apply below css

iff you want only first label of first div class

```
 .theclass1:first-child > label:first-of-type
```

[working DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/0zt4h02s/)

Comment: Why do you assume the OP is using HTML 4?

Comment: No I am just giving refrences

Comment: You are giving references about HTML 4 based on an assumption that the OP is using HTML 4.

Comment: I want to add HTML 5 link also but my reputation doesn't allow so :(

Comment: and that's why I have mentioned specially html4 not the html

Answer (score 0):

```
.theclass1 > div:first-of-type > div > div > label {
    color: red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/807t5L6z/

Comment: Thanks Kamil... And what about input checked state? (only the first) . Id like to give style to first label .

Comment: I don't know exactly what you mean, you should get familiar with css syntax: `.x .y` means class y within class x (no matter how deep), `.x > .y` is similar but only if .y is direct child of .x, `.x + .y` is when x and y are siblings, comma separated independent selections

Answer (score 0):

```
.theclass1 label:first-child {
color:red;
}
```

You could use this probably similiar code for label in .theclass2

Answer (score 0):

General answer is that "global first label in HTML" couln't be done, see here: [CSS global :nth-of-type selector (:nth-of-class)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13975475/css-global-nth-of-type-selector-nth-of-class)

And it's better to introduce class or id for this label.

However, if you want to target it without modifying HTML, you can use this selector:

```
label[for='1'] {
    background:red
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 .theclass1 > div > div > div label {color:red;}
```